# Keras custom loss function: ValueError in a tf.function-decorated

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, valueerror, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to implement in TF 2.2 the loss function from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.08623) (an existing version in TensorFlow 1.10.1, made by the author of the paper can be found [here](https://github.com/GuansongPang/deviation-network)).

However, the theoretical details of the loss function are not relevant to my problem.

My loss function:

```
def z_score_based_deviation_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    confidence_margin = 5.0     
    ref = K.variable(np.random.normal(loc=0., scale=1.0, size=5000), dtype='float32')
    dev = (y_pred - K.mean(ref)) / K.std(ref)
    inlier_loss = K.abs(dev) 
    outlier_loss = K.abs(K.maximum(confidence_margin - dev, 0.))
    return K.mean((1 - y_true) * inlier_loss + y_true * outlier_loss)
```

Calling it by:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=z_score_based_deviation_loss)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

I know there are other questions on this subject, but I haven't found any that are related to a custom loss function in Keras.
I can't figure out how to adapt it.

Also, from what I've read, the problem should exists when the function is tagged with `@tf.function` (which is recommended anyway to speed up the computation), but I didn't add it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way

```
def z_score_based_deviation_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    confidence_margin = 5.0     
    ref = tf.random.normal([5000], mean=0., stddev=1.)
    dev = (y_pred - K.mean(ref)) / K.std(ref)
    inlier_loss = K.abs(dev) 
    outlier_loss = K.abs(K.maximum(confidence_margin - dev, 0.))
    return K.mean((1 - y_true) * inlier_loss + y_true * outlier_loss)


X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,10))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 100)

x_input = Input((10,))
intermediate = Dense(1, activation='linear',  name = 'score')(x_input)
model = Model(x_input, intermediate)

model.compile('adam', z_score_based_deviation_loss)
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: it works, thanks! Can I ask you to explain why the problem was only in the generation of a `K.vairable`?

Comment: The problem was only in K.vairable... in general, using a variable inside loss doesn't seem to have much sense and look tricky, use a simple random generator, in this case, is enough. this behavior was also denied in tf2. Don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-)